# npm start fails after npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, expo

i create a sample project with (my os : Windows 10 ) ;

```
expo init test
cd test
npm start
```

everything works well and i can see my app on phone and my package.json looks ;

```
{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^30.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz",
  }
}
```

But if i want to install a package like "uuid" ;

```
npm install uuid
```

package is installed without problems , then i wrote ;

```
   npm start

This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]?
```

i press 'Y' , but it gives that errors ;

```
This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]? y
Installing the package 'expo-cli'...
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:362:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! empty-project-template@ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the empty-project-template@ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Package name is not important , if i install any package and run `npm start` , my project is down and i cant use my project, i tested this step with `yarn` , its same like `npm` , what is my mistake ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is just use `expo-cli start` , dont use `npm start` or `yarn start`.So it works without problems for now.

So if you want to create a react-native app with expo without problems , steps are :

- `expo-cli init [project-name]`
- `cd [project-name]`
- install any package if you need => `npm install package` or `yarn add package`
- `expo-cli start` ( dont use `npm start` or `yarn start` )
- done

Answer (score 6):

For those struggling with this issue,

1. Navigate to node_modules > .bin of the codebase
2. Find expo and expo.cmd in that directory
3. Rename it to anything.

You are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

For me, run `expo start` directly will work. Seems like `npm` does not know yet the existent of expo-cli

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. Please refer to [issue #51 of expo-cli](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/51) for follow-up.

Answer (score 0):

seems expo-cli is not installed correctly. 
try install it again:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

you might need to start a command shell as a administrator to run the command.

You'll also need to have Node.js (version 6 or newer) installed on your computer.

Comment: i did many times and also my version is newer ,  but if i install a new package it lost again , only solution is `expo init new-project` but it will broke after any installing package with `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I've downgraded version to "expo": "^30.0.0". It solves the same problem.

Comment: i did but doesnt work me , i tried same problem on linux (`opensuse thumbleweed`) , now i can work newest version both `expo` and `expo-cli` without problems with linux , but i didnt same thing on  my win 10 machine , for now i will use linux until find a way for win 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `expo-cli` to dev-dependencies with:

```
yarn add expo-cli --dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of Node.js you are using. 
But you can use this version Node.js 12.10.0. This can resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem. In my case, I was running an another app with Expo already and created a new App using Expo in an another window (thought it should not be a problem). Though I've received this error for my new App, when i start my existing App using `expo start` it starts the app without any issues. So, there is no issues with expo client or node version installed on my machine. There could be a problem with node module installation.

So, I've just exited from running App CLI and recreated a new App. Following the steps provided in [Setting up the development environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that I had a similar issue.  I did a clean install:

1. Open `cmd` and do `cd C:\`
2. Type: `npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save`
3. Allow this to finish
4. Go to `<windwos drive>\Users\<yourUser>\` and delete the `.expo` folder
5. Go back to the `cmd` and type: `npm install -g expo-cli --save`

It worked for me. It may work for you too.

https://www.thetopsites.net/article/52476154.shtml

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux try installing with expo-cli globally with this command:

```
sudo npm install -g expo-cli
```